# How to speed up getting file information of 10.000s of files

Tags: swift, macos, file, io

I need to collect a lot of data about picture and movie files in a directory (or a directory tree). This includes file name, date of creation and modification, filesize (and maybe later on additional data like size of picture - if available - which is not covered here). There are 10.000s of them. Wenn requesting 17.000 files the programm needs 10 min for doing this task.
I'm doing it with the following code, but is there a way to speed it up significantly?

This is the code I use:

```
// get files matching extensions
    func getPicFilenames(_ exts: [String]? = nil, includeFolders: Bool = false, skipHiddenFiles: Bool = true)
        -> Array<URL>
    {
        // all to upper once (and drop optional dot)
        let extUpper = exts == nil ?
            [String]() :
            exts!.map { ($0.hasPrefix(".") ? String($0.dropFirst(1)) : $0).uppercased() }
        // let resourceKeys = [URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey]

        // we also need size of files
        let resourceKeys = [ URLResourceKey.nameKey, URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey,
                             URLResourceKey.creationDateKey, URLResourceKey.contentModificationDateKey,
                             URLResourceKey.attributeModificationDateKey, URLResourceKey.fileSizeKey]

        var fileURLs: [URL] = []

        let directoryEnumerator = FileManager().enumerator(at: self, includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys,
                                                           options: skipHiddenFiles ? [.skipsHiddenFiles] : [], errorHandler: nil)!

        for case let fileURL as NSURL in directoryEnumerator {
            guard let resourceValues = try? fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: resourceKeys),
                let isDirectory = resourceValues[URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey] as? Bool
                else {
                    continue
            }

            // we can skip complete descendants! >> directoryEnumerator.skipDescendants()
            if !isDirectory || (isDirectory && includeFolders) {
                if let ext = fileURL.pathExtension {
                    // matching extension? (ignore case!)
                    if extUpper.count == 0 || extUpper.contains((ext.uppercased())) {
                        fileURLs.append( fileURL.absoluteURL! )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fileURLs
    }
```

This needs 1 min per 1.700 files. Wenn analyzing 100.000s files it should be much faster (if possible).

I'm using Swift 4.2 on XCode 10.1 with OSX 10.11.6.

Comment: What **hardware** are the files stored on?  "Normal" SATA drives can only do 50-70 separate IO operations per second.  If you assume something like 2 IO operations to get each file's metadata, that works out to 30 files/sec or 1,800 files/minute.  In other words, you need to buy faster disks.

Comment: :-) I'm trying to improve speed by brain, not by money. :-) The hardware is a MacBookPro 13" 2.3 GHz i5 from 2011 connected by Thunderbolt to a 2bay LaCie Drive. So I cannot afford new and faster hardware. If I'm not able to improve speed by a different approach, I have to wait for the existing solution. I don't know if there is a better one! Just a try!